# Difference between "scalar line integral" and "line integral"

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, curves

What is the difference between the phrases "scalar line integral" and "line integral"? If the phrases are equivalent, what purpose does the adjective "scalar" serve in the phrase; why is it there?

Comment: They might add 'scalar' to distinguish from the line integral of a *vector field*.

Comment: I agree with @StackTD, though the name is seemingly confusing in general: the line integral of a vector field is usually something like this $$\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r};$$ however, this still gives a scalar as an answer, and, at least at my university in the UK, integrals which give vectors as answers are also referred to as line integrals, i.e., things like $$\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$ and $$\int_{C}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}.$$ My point is that the name `scalar line integral' should probably be properly defined before it is used.

Answer (score 3):

In the calculus textbook that I learned multivariable calculus from (Marsden),

they had two terms, the **line integral** along a curve $C$ of a scalar function $f(x,y,z)$ given by

$$\int_Cf(x,y,z)\,ds.$$

Given a parametrization of the curve $C=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ this could be computed explicitly as a one-variable integral

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(x(t),y(t),z(t))\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt.$$

And then there's the **path integral** of the vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z).$ Which is denoted

$$\int\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)\cdot\,d\mathbf{s}.$$

It is a work computation, which only applies to vector fields, not to scalar functions. It is this latter integral which appears in the fundamental theorem of calculus, and Stokes' theorem.

I don't know source you used, or what your author had in mind, but my guess would be that what Marsden is calling a path integral, is what your author is calling a scalar line integral (it's the integral along a path of a scalar function). And what Marsden calls a line integral is what your author is calling a "line integral" (of a vector field).

Of course, if you give the name of your textbook, we can read the text to be sure of the answer.