# When to use ds vs dy and dx for line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Are $\int_{C}^{} f(x,y) ds $ and $\int_{C}^{} F(x,y) = \int_{C}^{} P(x,y) dx + \int_{C}^{} Q(x,y) dy$ equivalent to each other for some curve C? If not, when are they not interchangeable? And if so, when is there an advantage to using one over another?

Edit: it seems that the difference is when the function being integrated has $x$ and $y$ being multiplied or divided, i.e, inseparable into two separate functions. Is this correct?

Comment: The first is a scalar line integral, the second is a vector line integral.

Comment: What is the difference? Like I can parameterize c the same

Comment: What are $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: P and Q are just two component functions of $ F(x,y) $, i.e,  $ F(x,y) = P(x,y)i + Q(x,y)j $

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtII.aspx

Comment: Have you tried asking your prof? There are several notations for the integral of a scalar function along a curve, including $\int_C f$, $\int_C f(x,y)ds$, $\int_C f(x,y)\,dl$, $\int_Cf(x,y)\,dr$, $\int_Cf(r(x,y))\,dr$, etc., and a similar amount for vector functions. It may be more convenient to stick to whatever your professor uses and ask them why they use that particular notation.

Comment: Just posted on piazza but it's like 2 am lol

Comment: Related questions
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210398/why-a-line-integral-of-a-scalar-field-is-thus-a-line-integral-of-a-vector-field?rq=1
and 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739088/difference-between-scalar-line-integral-and-line-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking there is no real diffetence between ds, dx, and dy. Just that we integrate over a different variable.

However, s is commonly used as a path length parameter. And x and y are commonly used to integrate parallel to the x-axis respectively the y-axis.

In your case the first integral assumes that we can write x and y as functions of s. That is, we have x(s) and y(s) that parametrize the curve C.

The sevond integral integrates along the first parameter of P, which is x, which represents the coordinate along the x axis. It means that we consider y a function of x, that is y(x) so that it follows the curve C.

As an example consider $(x(s), y(s))=(\cos s,\sin s)$ and $(x,y(x))=(x,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ respectively $(x(y), y)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},y)$. These are 3 different parametrizations of the first quarter of the unit circle.

Comment: So then when do we use one over the other?

Comment: I thought I had just explained that. Can you clarify what is confusing you?

Comment: I'm just confused as to why there are two of the same thing then? Why would we use the first one rather than the second or vice versa?

Comment: Some examples might help

Comment: It's about how the curve C is parametrized... either with the x-coordinate as parameter, or something else...

Comment: Ah so if it's a circle: we could have $x^2 + y^2 = 4 $, but we could parameterize it in terms of sin and cos, or we could solve for x and y. Is that the difference?

Comment: Yes. I've just added an example of part of a circle.

Comment: Ok thanks! Very helpful!